# How do I add a add / import / include folder into resources folder from different project - gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build, resources, dependencies

I have two projects called `ProjectA` and `ProjectB`.

`ProjectA` has its property files in `ProjectB\FolderA`. `ProjectB` is already included as the dependency jar in `ProjectA`. But `ProjectA` cannot read `ProjectB\FolderA`. So I need to add `ProjectB\FolderA` to `ProjectA`'s resource folder.

How do I do this? `sourceSets`? or `include`. No idea at all.

Comment: How about packaging the resources into B's jar?